# Matching more than one word

Tags: python, regex

I've the following phrases and I'd like to match them:

> "De la Sota: Hello" -> "De la Sota"
>
> "Guini: Hello"      -> "Guini"
>
> "Prat Gay: Hello"   -> "Prat Gay"

I'm using `r"(\w+):"` but it only matches the last word before `:`.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're not using `split` or `partition`? Either of those may be more appropriate for your needs, e.g. `(before, colon, after) = str.partition("Dela Sota: Hello", ":")`

Comment: `str[:str.find(":")]`

Comment: \w matches any word character, i.e [a-zA-Z0-9_]. You could either use "." in place of \w or just use python's split function.

Comment: I'm not using the split method because this regex is one of many different patterns.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use this pattern:

```
/^(.*):/gm
```

Now `$1` is containing what you need.

#### [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qT5sJ4/2)

Noted that I'm pretty sure there is a better approach than regex for doing that. But I'm not a python expert.

Answer (score 2):

`str.split(":")[0]` should work, where `str` is your string you'd like to split.

```
>>> str = "De la Sota: Hello" 
>>> str.split(":")[0]
'De la Sota'
```

This works by splitting the string into a list, where the parameter is the delimiter. If you specify the colon as the delimiter, it will split the string into a list of individual phrases separated by the colon. The `[0]` just refers to the first value of the list, which is what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

change \w+ to .+ or .*:

```
input_text = ''' De la Sota: Hello

Guini: Hello

Prat Gay: Hello'''

print(re.findall(r'(.+):',input_text)
```

Comment: `DOTALL` is for matching newlines, it will match spaces even without the flag.

Comment: re.match only finds the first occurrence and also only in the beginning of the string. He would need to use .findall

Comment: fair enough.  I was looking at each of the 3 as separate examples, but you're right findall is probably a better generalization.

Answer (score 0):

```
"Prat Gay: Hello" -> "Prat Gay"
```

If that is exactly what you have you can use a negation set to get rid of `:`,  (using `\s` -- or if it is a tab using `\t`) and Helo because it is a set. As for names, some last name contain `-`, or  we need more than one occurrence of a character (`\w`) to make a name:

```
import re
string = ''' De la Sota: Hello

Guini: Hello

Prat Gay: Hello
'''
print(re.findall(r'[-\w ]+[^:\sHelo]', string))
```

gives the following answer:

```
[' De la Sota', 'Guini', 'Prat Gay']
```

You should use `re.findall` not `re.match` because the former looks in the entire string and the latter only matches with the first line and see if the string starts with it.